# How to execute MSBuild target recursively?

Tags: msbuild

I attempt to execute the following target but ends up with `circular dependency` error.  I do have a stop condition `$(Value) > 0` in target `Recursive`:

```
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003" DefaultTargets="Build">
  <Target Name="Recursive" Condition="$(Value) > 0">
    <PropertyGroup>
      <Value>$([MSBuild]::Subtract($(Value), 1))</Value>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <MSBuild Projects="$(MSBuildProjectFile)" Targets="Display" />
  </Target>

  <Target Name="Display">
    <Message Text="Value: $(Value)" />
    <MSBuild Projects="$(MSBuildProjectFile)" Targets="Recursive" />
  </Target>

  <PropertyGroup>
    <Value>10</Value>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <Target Name="Build">
    <MSBuild Projects="$(MSBuildProjectFile)" Targets="Display" />
  </Target>
</Project>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your stop condition is fine, but you forgot to pass the recalculated `Value` property into the next recursion. Change your `Recursive` target like this:

```
<Target Name="Recursive" Condition="$(Value) > 0">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Value>$([MSBuild]::Subtract($(Value), 1))</Value>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <MSBuild Projects="$(MSBuildProjectFile)" Targets="Display"
           Properties="Value=$(Value)" />
</Target>
```